# Can I match a string to a certain subtree of the AST?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-injection, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to use antlr4(+python3) to detect sql injection, and say now I have got the backend SQL command "SELECT * FROM AAA WHERE BBB = ''", and the user's input "CCC".

Now the parse tree looks like this:

[image]

My question is, can I match "CCC" (user's input) directly to the subtree "predicate" (see the figure above), i.e. enter the parse tree at "predicate"?

I have several ideas:

1. rewrite the grammar file
2. use visitors and jump over the nodes that are sure to appear before "predicate"

These ideas are complicated, so what should I look for in the existing literature? Or any other advice?

Comment: What's "predict"? Where did that come from?

Comment: "predict" is a typo, and I have changed it to "predicate", which is a node of the AST shown in the figure. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. use visitors and jump over the nodes that are sure to appear before "predicate"

Sure you can: when traversing the parse tree and you encounter the user input, just "walk" up the nodes until you encounter the node you're interested in. When traversing the parse tree, ANTLR give you the current parse context. This context has a `parent` context you can use to "walk" up the tree.